# Как проверить наличие роли у юзера в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я делаю бота для одной игры в дискорде. Мне нужно чтобы если у юзера забирали роль то тогда выполнялся какой-то код, в моём случае `config.players = config.players - 1`

Код:

```
@bot.event
async def ...(member):
  config.players = config.players - 1
  channel = ds.utils.get(user.guild.channels, id=950329905512595466)
  await channel.send(f'**{member}** вышел **{config.players}/10')
```

Каким методом в `discord.py` это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных манипуляций в `discord-py` есть специальное событие [**`on_member_update()`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    . . .
```

Функция будет вызываться при изменении данных (никнейм, роли и т.д.) любого участника сервера.

Аргумент `before` - это класс `discord.Member` с набором свойств, которые были до обновления данных пользователя

Аргумент `after` - тоже самое, что и `before`, но, соответственно, с актуальными данными

---

Далее просто проверьте **есть ли у `after` необходимая роль И была ли она у `before`**, так как нужно понять, что данное изменение - это именно удаление роли у пользователя.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, id=763333777266049024)

    # если такая роль была у пользователя И ее нет у него сейчас
    if role in before.roles and role not in after.roles:
        print(f'У {after.name} пропала роль {role.id}')
```

Для работы с `discord.Member` должны быть включены и выданы [**discord.Intents**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: А как вывести сообщение в чат?
Тоесть заменить `print` на `send`?

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Comment: вызовите функцию send у канала, в который нужно отправить сообщение

Comment: `channel = ds.utils.get(before.guild.channels, id=763333777266049024)`
`channel.send(f'**{after.name}** покинул зал ожидания **{config.players}/10**')`

Comment: можно просто через `channel = bot.get_channel(763333777266049024)`

Comment: а как сделать наоборот? если у юзера появилась роль?

Comment: Также, через проверку условий. Умение правильно строить такие условие - это ваша задача, так как вы программист. Ну, по сути нужно проверить, что такой роли нет у `before` и что она есть у `after` - логично же?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134684/discussion-between-s-smerch-and-denisnumb).